# Docker Compose: Is it possible to start a service before building another?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have an application that relies on redis being up for its integration tests.

I run my integration tests like inside a docker container like so:

**Dockerfile.test**

```
FROM clementoh/openjdk:jdk8-gradle-5.2.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./gradlew test
```

I am trying to use Docker Compose to run my tests like so:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:5.0.4"
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    environment:
      - SPRING_REDIS_HOST=redis
      - SPRING_REDIS_PORT=6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

The issue I have is that docker compose wants to build the web service first before starting redis and subsequently the web service. At this point, redis is not yet up so the tests being run in `Dockerfile.test` fail.

Is it possible to run the building of the web service after redis is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to execute `./gradlew test`.

Post that you can bring services up - 
`$ docker-compose up`

This way redis service will be brought up always before the entrypoint or CMD of web service executes.

Comment: Perfect! That makes a lot of sense and works for me. Appreciate it :) Will accept as answer in 2 minutes when StackOverflow lets me.